# Error en header Content-Lengt de request recibida en Express

Tags: javascript, api, express, rest, body

Tenemos una API desarrollada en Node.JS con Express, en la cual recibo una solicitud POST con Content-Type application/json. El problema es que uno de nuestros proveedores de "soluciones informaticas" que consume nuestra pieza nos esta enviando un valor fijo en el Content-Length , por lo que de entrada la solicitud es rechazada con un 400.

```
Content-Length:177
Content-Type:application/json
```

respuesta API:

```
{
"expose": true,
"statusCode": 400,
"status": 400,
"body": "algo",
"type": "entity.parse.failed"
```

}

Entiendo que debo indicarles que el content-length depende del cuerpo de la solicitud y no deben parametrizarlo con un valor en duro, pero el tiempo de respuesta de ellos es muy alto y es un problema que debemos corregir a la brevedad en producción. Hay alguna manera de, desde el lado de la API, manejar y solucionar este error al recibir una solicitud?

Configuracion de Express

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { appRoutes } from '../routes/index';
import morgan from 'morgan'
import cors from 'cors';

const server = express();

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(morgan('dev'));
server.use(cors());
appRoutes(server);

export default server;
```

Comment: Quizás esta pregunta te sea util https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223750/how-to-change-remove-ignore-a-http-header-just-before-parsing-the-response-in-no

Answer (score 0):

Si amigo, lo podes solucionar con el middleware de body-parse.
Para ignorar el Content-Length enviado por el proveedor y permitir que Express procese correctamente la solicitud podrias probar esto:

```
server.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '100kb',
  verify: (req, res, buf) => {
    req.rawBody = buf;
  }
}));
```

Espero que te sirva.